# How to automatically fill table based on certain rules (with JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have shift planning table created by JS and shown to user as html. This table is currently filled by user. I have certain set of rules and when user breaks them, he gets warning and he have to fix them.

I want to create script which fills this table automatically. I know how to do this, but i don't know how to do it so that script obeys all that rules and preferences.

For example. I cant give to all users all morning shifts. I need to have it so that one person have no more that 5 shifts in on week, have at least one free weekend, have no more than 20 shifts per month and have them layed out equaly all over the month (not all shifts at the start)

Is this even possible with javascript? If yes could you please give me some idea how?

My current idea is to use 'IF' to obey the rules, but i need to have some rules on same level, so if i use 'IF' and logical operators, but i am kinda stuck on it for days and i am not certain that this is right way to go.

[Fiddle with layout of table](https://jsfiddle.net/x04skpz1/)

Basic draft of my idea to fill table by rules:

```
function autoFill() {
var numberOfPeople = people.length;
var days = daysInThisMonth();
var ruleOne = ruleOneFunction(); //boolean
var ruleTwo = ruleTwoFunction(); //boolean
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
    for(var j = 1; j <= days; j++) {
        if(ruleOne === true && ruleTwo === true) {
            //fill table here
        }
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Your approach seems misguided. Generally I'd go about this as follows: First write a function that checks if an assignment of a shift to a person breaks any rules. Then iterate over all shifts on all days. For each shift choose that first person you can assign it to without breaking any rules.

Comment: Thank you that seems a lot better than my idea. I think that this might work :)